# How do i remove multiple MC's from the stage in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I create multiple MC's with the following code:

```
function addCharacter() {
    var newCharacter:characterBob = new characterBob();
    this.addChild(newCharacter);

    newCharacter.x=1000 - (50*counter);
    newCharacter.y=50;

    counter = counter + 1
}
```

Now i'd like to remove a bunch of them from the stage. Is there a way i can do this in AS3?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
for each (var o:DisplayObject in this) {
    if (o is characterBob) {
        removeChild(o);
    }
}
```

Perhaps a better option would be to put each "characterBob" created into an array. Then loop through the array and remove each object.

```
var bobs:Array = new Array();

function addCharacter() {
    var newCharacter:characterBob = new characterBob();
    this.addChild(newCharacter);

    newCharacter.x=1000 - (50*counter);
    newCharacter.y=50;

    counter = counter + 1;

    bobs.push(newCharacter);
}

function removeAllBobs():void {
    while (bobs.length > 0) {
        removeChild(bobs.shift());
    }
}
```

Comment: Corey has the answer. To wipe an mc i sometimes do: `while(this.numChildren) this.removeChildAt(0);`

Comment: How would i add each "characterBob" to the array?

Comment: Just create an array variable outside of your "addCharacter" function. Call it something like "bobs" like I did in my example. Then, in your "addCharacter" function, add something like `bobs.push(newCharacter);`

Comment: be careful and make sure that none of your MovieClip objects you are removing still have event listeners, etc.  you'll want to deactivate the object before you remove it or else you'll have memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(myDisplayObjectContainer.numChildren > 0){
    myDisplayObjectContainer.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

That will remove all children of the specified DisplayObjectContainer (Sprite or Movieclip)